# RegEx pattern that matches all possible variants of a regex pattern that matches a pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following regex pattern and I wanted to make sure that it'll only match regex that matches alphanumeric strings.

```
^\/\[(A\-Z|a\-z|0\-9){1}(?!\1)(A\-Z|a\-z|0\-9){1}(?!\2)(A\-Z|a\-z|0\-9){1}\]\/
```

And without character ranges just literal characters in case they don't use it the right way.

```
^\/\[(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|0123456789|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ){1}(?!\1)(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|0123456789|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ){1}(?!\2)(abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|0123456789|ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ){1}\]\/
```

I have a CTF chal that has the class writing a regex pattern that matches an alphanumeric string. I realize that the full characters aren't needed but I don't want them to fail if they don't immediately think to character ranges. I ran it manually with sed in extended mode, and regexr online but I am worried I might've missed something.

The second regex pattern is a second flag in case they don't utilize character ranges.

And it's not a "code golf" style question or at least to me it's not. I have the pattern I just need to verify that there's no weird obscure regex trickery that would produce a valid regex pattern that does what I told them to do that I've not covered via the preceeding two patterns.

I should say that I added an additional regex pattern(as CTFd allows multiple ones) that matched \w\d in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex matches only: `/[A-Za-z0-9]/` without anchors and quantifiers, I suggest you:

```
^\/\^?(?:\[(A-Z|a-z|0-9)(?!\1)(A-Z|a-z|0-9)(?!\1)(?!\2)(A-Z|a-z|0-9)\]|\[\^\\W_])[+*?]?\$?\/
```

that matches alphanumeric regexes with optional anchors and optional quantifiers, it matches also the short regex `/[^\W_]/` that means the same (i.e. Not non-word and underscore)

```
/[A-Za-z0-9]/
/[A-Za-z0-9]+/
/[A-Za-z0-9]*/
/^[A-Za-z0-9]/
/[A-Za-z0-9]$/
/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
/^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/
/^[A-Za-z0-9]?$/
/^[^\W_]+$/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6O6UBD/2)

Comment: This is what I was going for. I knew that there was other regex patterns out there that I hadn't thought of. I don't expect the students to be doing _anything_ more complex than just /[A-Za-z0-9]/ but I'd like to cover my bases.

Comment: @133794m3r: I just made a correction, it's mandatory to use `(?!\1)(?!\2)` before the last group, unless it matches `/[a-zA-Za-z]/`

Comment: I didn't catch that either in my tests. When I did it previously I din't have to do (?!\1)(?!\2) at the end because it didn't match any repeat patterns previously for some reason it felt like.

Comment: Well I didn't type my regex right. I completely forgot about the second lookahead reference for not matching. I meant to include it but I was a dum dum. Thanks for the help. I'll be utilizing this the skeleton of your RegEx for the other flags that require students to do RegEx. I don't think students will even known about +$*^ for the first few flags as they're going to just learn about RegEx in class before the CTF is opened up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that maybe you're trying to write some expression similar to:

```
^\/\[([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\1)([A-Za-z0-9])(?!\2)([A-Za-z0-9])\]\/
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B1AU7p/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YljSYx/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/YljSYx/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Yours didn't work for what I wanted. I wanted it to match any alphanumeric string pattern that they'd write in regex. So it'd have match /[A-Za-z0-9]/. Or the full character set one if they did it that way. I also modified the chain of character sets to utilize the \w\d optional ones and just made one that has two capture groups and references. My issue is that I want to match the regex pattern that matches a pattern.  Yours does not match the following perfectly valid regex pattern. /[A-Z0-9a-z]/. I should say though that I love that visualizer.